# input button to resize shape

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

Hi can someone please help me with getting the buttons to resize the shape. I have had a go myself but cannot get it to work. Below is the code I have so far thanks in advance

```
<html> 
<head>
<script>


function Smaller()
{
document.getElementById("rectangle1").height="50";
document.getElementById("rectangle1").width="50";
}



function resetsize()
{
document.getElementById("rectangle1").height="200";
document.getElementById("rectangle1").width="300";
}



 </script>
</head>
<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
  <rect id="rectangle1" x="150" y="0"  width="300" height="200"   />
</svg>


    <input type="button" onclick="Smaller" value="Smaller" />
    <input type="button" onclick="resetsize" value="ResetSize" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try the code I provided. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html> 
<head>
<script>

function smaller() {
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.height="50px";
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.width="50px";
}

function resetsize() {
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.height="200px";
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.width="300px";
}



 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="min-height:500px">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="width: 500px; height: 500px" id="rectangle1">
  <rect x="150" y="0"  width="300" height="200"   />
</svg>
</div>


    <input type="button" onclick="smaller()" value="smaller" />
    <input type="button" onclick="resetsize()" value="ResetSize" />

</body>
</html>
```

Please look at the on click propery of the buttons. And there is no id for yor svg element. :- )

Comment: thanks for your help is there a way of not making the buttons move when the shape is resized or do I have to use x and y coordinates for the buttons to prevent this?

Comment: @Len How about my changed code? Just wrap the rectangle inside a div and give it a minimum height. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can access a DOM element's CSS properties with the `style` attribute, like this:

```
function smaller() {
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.height="50";
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.width="50";
}

function resetsize() {
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.height="200";
    document.getElementById("rectangle1").style.width="300";
}
```

A few notes about your coding conventions: You typically want to having opening function brackets on the same line as the name of the function. Function names should be `camelCase` at all times; save `UpperCase` for class names only. Finally, make sure you tab in stuff inside of functions, if statements, etc. Your fellow developers will thank you. =)

---

Edit: make sure your HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="smaller()" value="Smaller" />
<input type="button" onclick="resetsize()" value="ResetSize" />
```

Comment: I have tried with and without the style attribute and it still doesnt work

Answer (score -2):

use jQuery to avoid this DOM abomination document.getElementById("fooo")